# Is the energy of an electromagnetic wave, in electron volts, an 'average' or a 'peak' value?

Tags: energy, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation

Since EM waves oscillate, is the energy given in eV an average or maximum value?

In a related question, can a detector (of whatever sort) 'miss' an EM wave if the amplitude is at a minimum when it goes past the detector?

Comment: With waves we talk about peak or average *power per unit area*, and this is not measured in electron-volts. With individual photons we talk about their energy, which can be measured in electron-volts, but the energy of a photon doesn’t oscillate.

Comment: We can still covert unit from J to eV though it may not have a valuable meaning in the classical context.

Comment: There is no way to know as context is lacking.

Comment: @G.Smith: That should be an answer.

Comment: @BenCrowell OK, I’ve made it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

With electromagnetic waves, we talk about peak or average power *per unit area*, but this is not measured in electron-volts. With individual photons, we talk about their energy, which can be measured in electron-volts, but the energy of a photon doesn’t oscillate.